# Unable to create tempDir. java.io.tmpdir is set to C:\windows\

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot, configuration

I am running the spring boot application by using bootRun gradle task and upon running its throwing the below error:

> Unable to create tempDir. java.io.tmpdir is set to C:\windows\

1. I have tried setting the path of java.io.tmpdir to `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local` in eclipse.ini file under -vmargs as mentioned:

   ```
   -vmargs
   -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local
   ```

   even after this I am getting the same error.
2. I even tried to set the path of java.io.tmpdir by passing it as JVM arguments in the run configuration like:

   ```
   -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local
   ```

   after doing so the application doesn't even run.
3. If I pass JVM arguments as `-Djava.io.tmpdir=$EXISING_DIR_WITH_WRITE_ACCESS`
   in the run configuration I get the following error:

   > finished with non-zero exit value 2

Comment: I‘m not a gradle user but i‘ll just make a guess. The third try is actually correct. Setting another tempDir in the JVM seems fine to me. I’m still wondering why your temporary path is at C://windows since this path is coming straight from the win32 api.  Is it possible that the “finished with non-zero exit value 2” has another origin?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why but it is not the first time that I see that the eclipse working directory is set to `C:\Windows` or `C:\Windows\System32`.

Just change the working directory in your run configuration to the desired location:
[image]